# php check if isset and value = 0

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the CodeIgniter framework to create my web services. I have an optional parameter that I want to set its value according to:-

- if it exists and has value 0, var2 = a
- else var2 = b

**Method 1**

```
    $foo = $this->post('foo');

    if(isset($foo) && $foo == 0) {
        $var2 = 'a';
    } else {
        $var2 = 'b';
    }
```

**Method 2**

```
    $foo = $this->post('foo');

    if(isset($foo)) {
        if ($foo == 0)
            $var2 = 'a';
        else
            $var2 = 'b';
    } else {
        $var2 = 'b';
    }
```

Both methods are returning `$var2 = 'a'` when I do not send in `foo`.

Comment: please check the value of echo $foo before if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below, both are same.

```
$foo = $this->input->post("username");
$var2 = (int)$foo === 0 ? 'a' : 'b';
```

OR

```
$foo = $this->input->post("username");

if((int)$foo === 0)
    $var2 = 'a';
else
    $var2 = 'b';
```

**NOTE:** you are using **`isset()`** to check an empty string. That is why it returns **`true`** always.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

you not using correct method to getting post value 
try

```
$foo = $this->input->post('foo');
if(empty($foo)) {
 $var2 = 'a';
} else {
    $var2 = 'b';
}
```

Comment: I think you are getting downvote for invalid answer. This if condition never return true for any condition.

Answer (score 1):

user this code

$foo = $this->input->post('foo');

```
if(isset($foo) && $foo == '0') {   

    $var2 = 'a';
} else {
    $var2 = 'b';
}
```

echo " variable =". $var2;

Output:

```
variable = a  // if you enter  0 in foo field

variable = b // if you didn't enter 0
```

You have to use single quotes around 0 (Zero) in if condition

```
if(isset($foo) && $foo == '0')
```

Comment: isn't this the same code he has used above in the question ?

Comment: he missed the  input.    $this->input->post('foo')

Comment: Ya, he missed it in the question. other wise it won't work. He said it always returns 'b'.

Comment: @IJas my apologies to all, I meant it was returning `a` when I want it to return `b`.

Comment: @IJas your answer was returning `a` when I want it to return `b` in the event `foo` is not sent in.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it using `=== '0'`.

```
$foo = $this->post('foo');

if($foo === '0') {
    $var2 = 'a';
} else {
    $var2 = 'b';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**$this->input->post()**

> The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are attempting to retrieve does not exist.

so instead try something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['foo']) && $_POST['foo'] == 0) {
    $var2 = 'a';
} else {
    $var2 = 'b';
}
```

**or**

```
$foo = $this->input->post('foo');
if($foo && $foo == 0){
    $var2 = 'a';
} else {
    $var2 = 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$foo = $this->input->post('foo');` 
var_dump($foo );

check the value of $foo
then write candition, may be $foo return false value